# Finding the inverse function of $f(x) = 5 - 4x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x)=5-4x^{ 3 }$$

Steps I took:

$$y=5-4x^{ 3 }$$

Subtracted 5 from both sides to isolate $x$

$$y-5=-4x^{ 3 }$$

Divided both sides by $-4$ to further isolate $x$

$$\frac { y-5 }{ -4 } =x^{ 3 }$$

Got rid of the exponent by getting the cubed root of both sides

$$\sqrt[3] { \frac { y-5 }{ -4 }  } =x$$

Interchanged x and y

$$\sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { x-5 }{ -4 }  } =y$$

The answer key has a different answer. How is this wrong?

Comment: what is the answer key ? What you did is correct.

Comment: it's not necessary to interchange $x$ and $y$ as long as you understand that $x=f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-5}{-4}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-(5-x)}{-4}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{5-x}{4}}$

Comment: @Vikram You just factored out the negative?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer,yes

Comment: What is the answer given?

Answer (score 2):

Just to summarize what was said in the comments, everything you did was correct. It's entirely possible that the answer key was wrong. The only other possible answer I can think of would be what Vikram suggested; aside from that, you're exactly right.

For a sanity check, you can graph the original function and your calculated inverse and see if the two graphs are reflections of each other across the line $y=x$ (which they are):

[image]